# Spring boot tomcat httpsession is not same when support both http & https

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, httpsession

I have HttpSession problem when using Embedded tomcat with Spring boot.
The scenario is as below:
I start tomcat with spring boot, support both http & https. my application using spring security saml to support SAML logon. During debug I found that saml/login & saml/sso can't get same http session. But if tomcat only support http or https, the http session is same. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A session created under https will not be accessible to an http request because the session cookie is marked as secure.

A session created under http should be accessible to an https request.

Comment: My request is under same HTTP scheme, the redirect is under http too, my question is not asking share session betthttp & https. My question is when tomcat support both http & https, it makes the http SAML request has different session even the request all http request